# Incorrect code in firefox Notifications.jsm and strange behaviour

Tags: android, firefox-addon-sdk

I am using notifications.jsm to provide notification for downloads from Downloads.jsm.  The following code is incorrect in notifications.jsm :

```
  unregisterHandler: function(key, handler) {
let i = _handlersMap[key].indexOf(handler);
if (i > -1) {
  _handlersMap.splice(i, 1);
}
```

},

_handlersMap is an object, so splice is not a function.

Additionally, perhaps because of the unregisterHandler method being incorrect, there are occasions when having uninstalled my addon and create a new Notification in the reinstalled addon I am getting dead objects in the observe method.
My code creates a separate handler for each new notification with a handlerKey incremented by one for each new download.  For the different observe event types the code is similar, the handlers for the key are iterated and the corresponding method is called.  Since I have registered a different handler for each notification there should be only one handler for that key to call but this is not the case, there are dead objects from the previous addin that have the same key from the new addon.  Surely this behaviour is not correct.

Please can someone look at this and the other posts that I have made regarding the firefox sdk.  I only thought that Microsoft could provide undocumentation, in fact this is much worse as the documentation is nonsense and the code that is being provided has errors.

Regards

Comment: If you're using the add-on SDK why don't you simply use the [notifications module](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/notifications)?

Comment: Because it does not have the required functionality.  Notifications module does not show progress and does not provide the facility to add multiple buttons for click handling and can be swiped away.